# Delete certain values from a hashmap where values is a list

Tags: java, list, hashmap, key-value

I've a map which looks like

```
myNum<String,List<Integer>> = {key=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]}
```

I picked up the numbers 3, 8, 1 (based on some condition) from the value which is a List, now I need to update the value list to remove these numbers and update the map as
  {key=[2,4,5,6,7]}

How can I do that?

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `map.get(key).remove(3)` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally, and making the assumption that the map you are using is one of the Java standard library maps, then the `List` you receive from `Map#get` will always be a reference to the last `List` you passed to `Map#put`.

As they are references to the same `List`, `List#removeAll` should do the trick.